# How to use generics with composition in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm having issues with generics types in Dart. Take the following entities example in consideration:

```dart
enum ProductType { book }

abstract class ProductMetadata {
  ProductMetadata(this.type);
  
  final ProductType type;
}

class BookProductMetadata extends ProductMetadata {
  BookProductMetadata(this.pages) : super(ProductType.book);
  
  final int pages;
}

abstract class Product<M> {
  Product(this.metadata);
  
  final M metadata;
}

class BookProduct extends Product<BookProductMetadata> {
  BookProduct(BookProductMetadata metadata) : super(metadata);
}
```

Where we would have multiple different kinds of `product` with different kinds of `metadata`. I'm trying to build a serializer that support this structure, and I stuck with the following:

```dart
class ProductSerializer {
  Product<M> from<M extends ProductMetadata>(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final metadata = json['metadata'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final type = metadata['type'] as ProductType;
    
    ProductMetadata formattedMetadata;
    
    switch (type) {
      case ProductType.book:
        formattedMetadata = BookProductMetadata(123);
    }
    
    return BookProduct(metadata: formattedMetadata);
    }
}
```

Which gives me the error `A value of type 'BookProduct' can't be returned from the method 'from' because it has a return type of 'Product<M>'`.

The goal in this serializer was to avoid at most type-casting using `as` and to use generics for whoever uses this serializer to determine what should be its returning type. I was able to achieve a similar example in a `Typescript` project, but I am not being able to take full advantage of generics in Dart and I can't understand why, since it seems natural to me that `BookProduct<BookMetadata>` should be accepted as `Product<M>` when `M extends ProductMetadata`.

Comment: `BookProduct<BookMetadata>` can't be returned from a generic function `from<M>` because what would happen if, say, someone called `from<int>`?  `BookProduct<BookMetadata>` is not a subtype of `Product<int>`, and the compiler cannot guarantee that `from<M>` will never attempt to return a `BookProduct<BookMetadata>` for arbitrary values of `M`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid casting.

The code

```dart
    switch (type) {
      case ProductType.book:
        formattedMetadata = BookProductMetadata(123);
    }
    
    return BookProduct(metadata: formattedMetadata);
```

suggests that your function always returns a `BookProduct`.

Which it does, because `book` is the only existing product type, but I'd expect that to change. If there were more product types, then the switch would not be exhaustive, and the following code would not be able to know that the `formattedMetadata` is always `BookProductMetata`.

Assume there was also a `MovieProductMetadata` implementing `Metadata`, and a `MovieProduct` implementing `Product<MovieProductMetadata>`.
In that case, the static type system sees a function with type `Product<M> Function<M extends ProductMetadata>(...)` which returns a `BookProduct` implementing `Product<BookProductMetadata>`.
It *cannot* assume that to be valid, because `M` could be `MovieProductMetadata`. (Or, even without those extra types, `M` could always be `Never`, it's a subtype of any type.)

If you had more cases, the return should probably be inside the switch case.
If it was inside the switch case, you don't need the shared `formattedMetadata` variable, and could have done:

```dart
    switch (type) {
      case ProductType.book:
        var formattedMetadata = BookProductMetadata(123);
        return BookProduct(metadata: formattedMetadata) as Product<M>;
      case ProductType.movie: ...
    }
```

*You still need the `as` cast*, because static analysis cannot see why a `BookProduct` should be guaranteed to be a `Product<M>` for *every*  valid `M`.
It requires the caller to know, ahead of time, which type of product is going to be returned for the JSON they put in. Which is fine, but that still means at least one runtime check, like the `as`.

The type of the returned object depends on the *value* of the metadata type in the incoming JSON. That's dependent typing (types depending on runtime values), and Dart's static type system can't do that. That's why you need runtime type checks too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Irn! I'm just confuse about this cast need because that could be "internally" made by Dart for this function called, like: `final book: MovieProduct<MovieMetadata> = bookSerializer.from(...)`. Inferring the return type could be this cast. I understand that in this situation, the case will be made anyways, but I still take the advantages of using generics and this cast would be made "internally" by Dart. Basically we can't do that because of dependent typing?

Comment: Dart 2.0 removed most implicit casts from the language. Those casts were inserted where something needed to be a subtype of the static type it had, and the compiler could therefore figure out which type it needed to have and it did a cast to that type for you. That also hid a lot of bugs that would only arise at runtime. So, now you have to write an explicit cast whenever you know something about the type that the compiler doesn't know that it certainly has that type. So, no "internal"/implicit casts any more (except from `dynamic`).

Comment: Got it, but do you know why the compiler can't assume the generic that I'm sending to the function as the return type? As an example, in the example above, the compiler itself do in the end `BookProduct(metadata: formattedMetadata) as Product<M>`. Why do I have to explicitly do this cast since it's expected that the function needs to return this exactly same type? I'm not sure how Typescript and other languages does that, but as far as I can remember Dart is the first one that I need to do this

Comment: The static type of `BookProduct(metatadata: formattedMetadata)` is `BookProduct` which is a `Product<BookProductMetadata>`. The return type is `Product<M>`. Those are not the same. The *static type analysis* cannot see that `Product<BookProductMetadata>` is a subtype of `Product<M>`. It doesn't know what `M` is, for all it knows, `M` could be `Never`. There are ways to call the function which would make the return invalid. So, you need the cast.